# Creating a mutiboot USB from linux

Tags: linux, usb, multi-boot

There are many tools out there ([YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), [SARDU](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/sardu-multiboot-usb-creator-windows/), etc.) which allow for easy creation of  multiboot linux USB drive from Windows. Are there any similar tools for linux (general, not disro-specific)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out, maybe it will help:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MH-khdiXqYs

Comment: Please include the most important steps here, on-site. As you should know, link-only answer are not encouraged.